# How can I style the pivot header with fixed elements?

Tags: .net, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

On my UI, I have a Pivot control that basically holds the state of 3 different displays that all work with each other (i.e. an update to any of the 3 PivotItems can affect any of the other 2). The effect that I'm going for is to have the 3 pivot "tabs" behave as they normally do (highlighting as its respective view id displayed), but I'd like to have a fixed element as well that does not move but does have some data bindings in it:

```
Page1  Page2  Page3
---------------------------------

Some fixed elements that never move

---------------------------------
PivotItemView/Content
```

So what it would look like is that when the user swipes left or right, the content will change, the tab will change, but the static content will appear pinned down.

I was able to figure out how to customize the tabs items by specifying the data template, but this will apply for every PivotItem that is defined. How can I define a fixed area?

UPDATE:
I may have found out a way to do it but I'm not sure how to account for the bound element in the fixed area I spoke of.

I've modified the Pivot style and placed my fixed content in a new grid row above the ItemsPresenter. But how do I bind the text property of a textblock in the pivot style to a property on the DataContext of the Pivot instance?

Answer (score -1):

UX wise that's not a good thing to do. Content under the pivot item is linked to that tab by the user. If you need the same data on every tab, use a custom control and databinding for that OR place that content above the pivot control.

Martin